# Is there a term for this kind of video game background?

Tags: terminology

Ok, I have an odd little question.

I'm sure that I've played a number of video games with this kind of stylized 2D background, though I can't think of an good example for the life of me (I tried, promise):

Instead of a single background image, this kind of background has several 2D images stacked on top of each other. If you move a little left or right, the images shift a just a little bit accordingly. You might see a little more of one image or another, but the overall effect is to create a kind of 2D depth of vision, like a paper diorama.

That isn't the best description, but hopefully gets the memory across.

**So, my question:** Does this kind of background have a name?

Comment: Hmm. Either our terminology tag is incomplete, or we should take another look at [this meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11467/do-we-want-to-support-is-there-a-term-for-x-questions).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's called [Parallax scrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling).

> Parallax scrolling, also known as "Asymmetrical scrolling",[citation
>   needed] is a technique in computer graphics and web design, where
>   background images move by the camera slower than foreground images,
>   creating an illusion of depth in a 2D scene and adding to the
>   immersion.[1] The technique grew out of the multiplane camera
>   technique used in traditional animation[2] since the 1930s. Parallax
>   scrolling was popularized in 2D computer graphics and video games by
>   the arcade games Moon Patrol[3][4] and Jungle Hunt,[5] both released
>   in 1982. Some parallax scrolling had earlier been used by the 1981
>   arcade game Jump Bug.[6]